# new to ubuntu need to intall it properly with my new SSD

Tags: software-installation

Hi my laptop crashed recently so I bought a new SSD (500gig) as well as a new operating system (ubuntu 64-bit) I have a Dell i5 laptop.i use my laptop for Photoshop, adobe after effects basicly most of adobe software. And so I need to install this OS properly so that it will function properly with my intensive adobe software. I have 6 gigs of ram .how do go about installing it and partitioning it properly without using up to much space for partitioning and to make my SSD work nicely cos its been said that'it is faster then your normal hardrive. And I previously had Windows 7

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking but why switch to Ubuntu if you heavily rely on so much Windows software?  Photoshop and After Effects won't be as smooth and hassle-free as on Windows.

Comment: Hi thing is I have an assignment due thursday an since mylaptop crashed I couldn't get hold of a Windows operating system ,but I got hold of ubuntu OS .I really  would have liked a windows OS but unfortunately I couldn't find 1 one so that's my reason

Comment: If you have an assignment due Thursday, learning a new operating system now might not be the best use of your spare time.  You are also probably not going to get After Effects to work as I note in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [instructions for installing Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) onto an SSD are no different than for a traditional hard drive.  The default partitioning recommended by the installer will be suitable.

The speed benefits of an SSD do not require special configuration of the OS.

It wasn't a main part of your question, but you are going to run into difficulties getting Photoshop and After Effects running on Ubuntu (with Wine).  After Effects in particular probably won't work at all if you have version 9 or later (CS4 or later) ([source](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=648)).

Adobe Photoshop CS5 won't run, and Adobe Premiere Pro beyond version CS3 won't run.  Other versions will run with problems or will be difficult to get working ([source](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=vendor&iId=12&sAction=view&sTitle=View+Developer)).

Comment: I have the cs5 suite and 14.04 64-bit ubuntu. Will it not work at all

Comment: According to the WineHQ database Photoshop CS5 and After Effects CS5 won't work.  Same with Premiere Pro CS5 and Illustrator CS5.  Those results are based on reports by people who have tried to use them.

Comment: Thanks alot Thomas I'll try getting getting the windows OS